# Initialize auth component (firebase-laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, firebase, firebase-authentication

I try to initialize the auth method but after I login it keeps showing me `invalid API key` error message:

[image]

This is how I initialize my auth component:

[image]

using `app()` helper give my the same error too.

This is my login method:

[image]

But if I set env variable of my `.json` file [image],

it gives me this error:

[image]